# How to count the number of files having a specific string in their filename in a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I want to count the number of files having a specific string in their filename in a specific folder in Drive. For example I want to count all files that have the string "final" in their name in a specific folder. I am able to get it to work by giving the search string within quotes, but not if i pass it as a variable.

See lines commented as // doesn't work and // works below. Appreciate any help

```
function countNumFiles(){
  var searchString = "some string";
  const folderID = 'Replace_with_folder_id';

  var searchFor = 'title contains ' + searchString ; // doesn't work
  //var searchFor = 'title contains "some string"'; // works
  
  var filesArray = [];
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).searchFiles(searchFor);
  
  while (folder.hasNext()) {
    var file = folder.next();
    filesArray.push(file.getName());
  }
  Logger.log(filesArray.length);
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var searchFor = 'title contains ' + searchString ;
```

#### To:

```
var searchFor = `title contains '${searchString}'`;
```

or

```
var searchFor = "title contains '" + searchString + "'";
```

Comment: var searchFor = "title contains '" + searchString + "'"; worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am trying to call this function from Sheets. So I have made searchString an argument to the function. I now invoke it as countNumFiles(searchString) But it gives an error. Do I have to enable any settings since I am using DriveApp?

Comment: The Error message is Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 11).

Comment: @user1327454 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from your comment. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I think that I have to study more. In the current stage, I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @user1327454 In order to correctly understand your new question, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @user1327454 Now, I thought that I might understand your new question from `I am trying to call this function from Sheets.` and `The Error message is Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 11).`. If you are trying to use your script as a custom function, unfortunately, that cannot be directly achieved because of the current specification of the Google side. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: @user1327454 If my understanding is correct, how about using OnEdit trigger? But in this case, your new question is different from your initial question. So I would like to recommend do post it as new question. Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to call it as custom function. Thanks for the suggestion of trying OnEdit trigger.

Answer (score 1):

#### Find Search String in File Name for files in a given folder

```
function countFilesWithStringsInNames() {
  const s = "searchstring";//enter search string
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid');
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  let found = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if(~file.getName().indexOf(s)) {
      found.push(file.getId())
    }
  }
  Logger.log(found.length);
}
```

or with Drive API Version 2:

```
function countFiles() {
  const s = "title search string";
  const folderid = "folderid";
  const files = Drive.Files.list({supportsAllDrives : true,q:`title contains '${s}' and parents in '${folderid}'`}).items;
  let o = files.map(items => [items.id]);
  Logger.log(o.length);//o contain a column of ids for each file found
}
```

Comment: I am trying to call this function from Sheets. So I have made searchString an argument to the function. I now invoke it as countFiles(searchString) But it gives an error. I have added DriveAPI in service settings in Apps Script. Do I have to enable any settings ?

Comment: The Error message is Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || googleapis.com/auth/drive)